# Deterministic epoch to date

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, persistent, deterministic

i have a bigint column in a table containing unix/epoch times (excluding milliseconds); eg. 1610278178 (2021-01-10T11:29:38+00:00)
i want to have a persisted computed column which converts epoch to date (so not datetime!)

i came up with this and it works, but it seems a bit long...

```
[date] as CONVERT(date, DATEADD(s, CONVERT(int, [unixtime]), CONVERT(datetime, DATEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1))), 112) PERSISTED
```

is there a shorter/faster version with the same result?

Comment: Are you sure you need `PERSISTED`? This is not necessary to index the computed column, while if the column is *not* indexed it may be detrimental rather than beneficial to performance (calculating the value on demand may end up less expensive than the overhead of the additional I/O). `PERSISTED` is only really required for floating-point calculations. In any case, a short deterministic version is `CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(SECOND, [unixtime], 25567))`. The mysterious `25567` is `CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '19700101'))`, using the fact that integer-to-`DATETIME` conversion is deterministic.

Comment: A less mysterious but longer version can use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)`, as you (almost) do in your original code. Note that you do not need to bother with conversion styles here; this is relevant only for string conversions, of which there are none.

Comment: am i sure? no. but good suggestion, i am going to check it and see which one performs best. thanks! 
i like the 25567 alternative, going to use it if i stay with persisted. 
but even if i drop the persisted, i guess your 25567 alternative is still the shortest version, right? or even better suggestions in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If your UNIX timestamps are only 10 digits then you can do this

```
select dateadd(s,1610278178,'1970-01-01')
```

If you have the full 13 digits, most divide by 1000 which rounds to the nearest second.